# Displaying Time After the Game Is Over as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

hey i am new with ac3.

this is my code for the timer:

its started in frame 1
in the end of the game it's continue to frame 3.

i dont know how to show the timer there...

```
 var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
 timer.start();
 timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTickHandler);
 var timerCount:int = 0;
        function timerTickHandler(Event:TimerEvent):void
  {
timerCount += 100;
toTimeCode(timerCount);
   }

   function toTimeCode(milliseconds:int) : void {
//create a date object using the elapsed milliseconds
var time:Date = new Date(milliseconds);

//define minutes/seconds/mseconds
var minutes:String = String(time.minutes);
var seconds:String = String(time.seconds);
var miliseconds:String = String(Math.round(time.milliseconds)/100);

//add zero if neccecary, for example: 2:3.5 becomes 02:03.5
minutes = (minutes.length != 2) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds.length != 2) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;

//display elapsed time on in a textfield on stage
timer_txt.text = minutes + ":" + seconds+"";
    }
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything flagrantly wrong with your code. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Timer function isn't what you want.  That's for a countdown.  You just want to count up, which requires recording when you started, and deducting that from the current runtime.

```
import flash.utils.*;
var start:Number = flash.utils.getTimer();

function showElapsedTime():void {
    trace(toTimeCode(flash.utils.getTimer() - start));
}
```